# Opencv hough circles perform better if I resize image to double the size

Tags: opencv, hough-transform

I have an image like below :

[image]

I am trying to detect the circles via HoughCircles function.
Prior to detection, I threshold the image, and blur it via gaussian technique. The result is like follows :

[image]

The inverted image is larger, because I happened to find out that, if I dont resize image with same aspect ratio, hough circles algorithm goes nuts and finds either very few circles, or very wrong set of circles. I do understand the hough transformation algorithm to an extent. I use this snippet to detect the circles :

```
circles = cv2.HoughCircles(invertedBlurredImg, cv2.HOUGH_GRADIENT, 1, 30, param1=100, param2=23, minRadius=7, maxRadius=20)
```

I tried a lot of different dp values ranging from 1 to 2. I do think that if I get it close to 2, the sensitivity drops and, it becomes somewhat more possible to find the circles in a bad quality image. However, even if I dont enlargen the inverted image, I think the circles are quite clear, and I dont understand why it cannot find all the circles, unless I enlargen the image.

Here are the detected circle in case of the original sized image, and enlarged image, respectively.

[image]

[image]

What is the positive effect I receive from enlarging the image?
Does it kinda work like dilation because of the interpolation that goes on during the resizing to a larger image ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You had a problem and you have solved it in another way. Your problem is the parameters of the `HoughCircle`. They are too high for your small circles. Instead of changing them, you changed the image size. Thus gave you a good results since your new image is suitable for the old paramters.

The solution is to change your `HoughCircle` parameters until you got a good results on your original image. I am pretty sure it is the `minRaduis` which need to be decreased a bit.

Comment: Not that i did not try what you said, I do understand how hough circle detection algorithm , so i dont think that is the peoblem. As you can see, even when the image was small, some little circles were indeed detected. Plus, minRadius being 0, it has no negative effect on the outcome. The problem is simply something else, but i dont know what it is.